# Linking libssh statically for MinGW

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, libssh

I am trying to statically link libssh to my project which is built using a mingw/mysys makefile, however no matter what I try I get a whole bunch of undefined reference errors. I've spent hours researching this but I still can't fix it. Below is my makefile and some example output. I also compiled the libssh.a file using cmake with the WITH_STATIC_LIB option set to 1. I don't understand how I can continue to get these errors even though my linker can find the libssh.a file. Did I build it incorrectly?

#### Example output:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build/BMU.o: in function `ZN3ssh7SessionC1Ev':
./include/libssh/libsshpp.hpp:130: undefined reference to `_imp__ssh_new' 
.
.
.
```

#### Makefile

```
CC          := g++
TARGET      := "dist/target"
BUILDDIR    := build
SRCDIR      := src
CFLAGS      := -std=c++17 -g  -mconsole 
SRCEXT      := cpp
SOURCES     := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.$(SRCEXT))
OBJECTS     := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%, $(BUILDDIR)/%, $(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))
INCLUDE     := -I./include
LIB         := -L./lib -lws2_32 -lssh -lmodbus -static

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.$(SRCEXT)
    @printf "\e[33m\e[1mBuilding...\e[0m\n";
    @mkdir -p $(BUILDDIR)
    @echo "  $(notdir $@) from $(notdir $<)"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -c -o $@ $<

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @printf "\e[35m\e[1mLinking...\e[0m\n";
    @mkdir -p dist
    @echo "  $(notdir $(OBJECTS))"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIB)
```

#### Building Libssh:

First I did
`git clone https://git.libssh.org/projects/libssh.git libssh`

then using cmake-gui built it for MySys makefile with 'WITH_STATIC_LIB" set to 'ON' and 'WITH_SHARED_LIB' to 'OFF'

Then I ran `make` from my terminal and it created a libssh.a file which I moved to the `./lib` folder in my project.

The make file was able to find the libssh.a file but I still got these errors.

Any help is appreciated and yes I looked a tons of other stackoverflow posts before posting myself.

#### Other things I tried

`#define LIBSSH_STATIC 1` and without it

using vcpkg to install libssh, but this generates a .lib file which has the same problems as the .a file

### Edit:

Including LIBSSH_STATIC causes the output to look like:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./lib\libssh.a(channels.c.obj):channels.c:(.text+0x1979): undefined reference to `_imp__ssh_buffer_add_data'
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct CMake parameter for building static libraries (including for libssh) is `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF`

As long as you're seeing `_imp__` in the `undefined reference to` errors your linker is looking for the symbols exported from a shared library (DLL).

To make sure the project that uses libssh looks for the static library you must define `LIBSSH_STATIC`, for example by adding compiler flag `-DLIBSSH_STATIC` to `CFLAGS` in your `Makefile`.

Comment: After doing that I get a bunch of errors that look like this: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ./lib\libssh.a(channels.c.obj):channels.c:(.text+0x1979): undefined reference to `_imp__ssh_buffer_add_data'

Comment: Looks like it's still looking for dllimport symbols. Are you sure you compiled with the `-DLIBSSH_STATIC` flag?

Comment: Can you try with this version https://www.libssh.org/files/0.9/libssh-0.9.4.tar.xz ? I have no issues with that version.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I get the same issue @Brecht Sanders However I forgot to mention that when compiling I get this error: #error "Your system must have getaddrinfo()" which I fixed by just commenting that line out. I'm not sure if that's an issue or not

Comment: Thank you for continuing to help me though I really appreciate it!